# When to use "am besten" and when to use "am liebsten"?

Tags: word-choice

> Welche Idee gefällt Ihnen am besten?
>   Welche Reise würden Sie am liebsten buchen?

Why would I use *am besten* in the first sentence and *am liebsten* in the second one? Is there any rule for their use?

Comment: Try and say "Wie begeht man am besten Selbstmord" vs. "Wie begeht man am liebsten Selbstmord"

Comment: Sorry i didnt get the example im not very good at deutsch .

Comment: N88, tofro only get's a notification that you replied to the comment if you use @tofro

Comment: @Iris Almost. Since tofro was the first one to comment, he should've gotten a notification. It's even possible that N88 did use the @-syntax but it was automatically removed by the system. Anyhow, in general your note is true and worth mentioning.

Comment: @N88 "Am liebsten" can only be used for something you *like* (at least a bit) - So my suicide example does not work with it. It would, however, somewhat work with "am besten".

Comment: @Em1 No, I did not receive a notice, even If I was the first to comment, for whatever reason.

Comment: @tofro Or maybe ‘Wie begeht man am Liebsten Selbstmord’? ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is really not that complex, provided we start at the core of it. **Am besten** is from the group: gut, besser, am besten. These describe quality:

> Gut, besser, am besten = well, better, best
>
> Wo fischt man am besten? = where to fish best?
>
> Welche Suppe schmeckt am besten? = which soup tastes best?

**Am liebsten** is from the group: gern, lieber, am liebsten. They describe something entirely different, namely, how gladly something is done!

> Gern, lieber, am liebsten= gladly, more gladly, most gladly

Hence you could easily prefer fishing in a place that is not so good for fishing, because it is, for instance, tranquil:

> Am besten fischt man hier, aber am liebsten gehe ich dort hin. Dort ist es viel ruhiger!

Similarly, someone's husband might cook better than someone else, but not quite as gladly:

> Mein Mann kocht besser als mein Bruder, aber nicht so gern. Am liebsten mache ich es selbst.

You probably got curious, because you chose to use **"gut gefallen"** in your second example, which means "to like well". This contains "well", but expresses gladness, hence your confusion.